# Form data not passing to PHP file

Tags: javascript, mootools

#### The Program I'm writing and the functionality I'm trying to achieve

Okay. So what I'm writing at the moment is a very simple forum, in Javascript using AJAX. Part of my task is to add a new post, using an API that my lecturer wrote for us in PHP. Just to note, the API and the SQL database are completely local.

The function I am using to add this post is:

```
function addPosts()
{
// Add the new thread to the SQLlite database.
var treq = new Request({
    url:'guestbook/control.php?action=insertPost',
    'method':'post',
    onSuccess: function() {
        alert('win');
    },
    onFailure: function() {
        alert('fail');
    }
}).send(Object.toQueryString({
    // Had to convert it to a query string because it wouldn't work as a normal object.

    // These are the required values to send, to store a "post" in the database.
    'name':'This is a name',
    'comment':'This is a comment!'
}));
}
```

I am aware this will add the same data every single time. I'm just trying to get the damn thing working!

#### The problem

What is happening is, when this function is called, I am getting an SQL syntax error. I was confused, because that would imply that my lecturer's code is wrong. After speaking with my lecturer, he explained that this happens when the post data isn't sent correctly to the PHP code. So I went about using Google Chrome's developer tools to see what was going on, and this is what I discovered:

[image: screenshot of post data]

Now to me, this means that the data is successfully being loaded into the request, and is being passed to the PHP files fine. Obviously I'm wrong. I've been racking my brains trying to make this work.

I know that the API works fine, because everyone else in my class isn't having any problem with it, and the code I am using is practically a rip off of the code in the notes, so I'm about 90% sure that's correct to.

One thing to note is that the code in the `onSuccess` key runs, so I know it's not a problem on the AJAX side.

Another thing is that this code worked in University on those computers, and it's since I've got it home that it's decided not to work.

**Stack Trace**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")": syntax error' in G:\Ajax
>   Coursework\guestbook\php\database.php:134Stack trace:#0 G:\Ajax
>   Coursework\guestbook\php\database.php(134): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO
>   pos...')#1 G:\Ajax Coursework\guestbook\php\class.GuestBook.php(44):
>   DatabaseHandler->insert(Array)#2 G:\Ajax
>   Coursework\guestbook\control.php(8): GuestBook->insert(Array)#3
>   G:\Ajax Coursework\guestbook\control.php(56): insertPost()#4 {main}
>   thrown in G:\Ajax Coursework\guestbook\php\database.php on line 134

Comment: Taking a look at the stacktrace it seems the exception is launched when trying to insert a new Post (PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO pos') Can you access to the SQLite database?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your installation of php/sqlite and nothing to do with your or the instructor's code.  Try writing a php script that adds something simple to the database and see if it fails.

Comment: @James I thought the same. I was more worried that I was missing a silly mistake is all. The thing is, it's the posting of data that's the problem. all requests are executed perfectly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the post request per se like people told you. as you can see in chrome inspector the "form data" section indeed sends 2 parameters name & comment with the correct values - so the error have to be in the server - or the way you install or some error on your lecturer code(yes - they can be wrong too - surprise). If you want us to help you post the code for the server side

Comment: I've seen the code work perfectly though. That's the issue. I keep thinking it's a change in environment that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Object.toQueryString is used in convert an object to a query string. So if the server is requiring both $_POST['name'] and $_POST['comment'] to be set, it wont be.

Frankly because you are posting it, I dont think $_GET['name'] or $_GET['comment'] would be set either.

Request.send expects an opject. You are sending it a string. So it should be 
Request.send({prop: 'value'}), not Request.send(value).

Do yourself a favor and make a PHP with the following php code, and see what it returns. It may clear this up for you right away. I have a feeling nothing is being sent except for $_GET['action']

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi. It actually doesn't work with an object (Why, I don't know. Weakly typed languages for you). IT works fine with a Query string. I also fixed my issue by switching to Mozilla.. I don't really know what difference it made, but it works like a dream.

Comment: The posted code would probably answer why it works with the query string and not an object. Im guessing if you change type from POST to GET, it would take an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just in-case anyone stumbles upon this thread looking for an answer:

```
function addPosts()
{
// Add the new thread to the SQLlite database.
var treq = new Request({
    url:'guestbook/control.php?action=insertPost',
    onSuccess: function() {
        alert('win');
    },
    onFailure: function() {
        alert('fail');
    }
}).post('name=This is a name&comment=This is a comment!');
}
```

Here I'm using the .post method to POST data.

Comment: Sorry, I really should have updated this. It turned out as soon as I moved the site over from Chrome to Firefox it worked fine.